# Zend Framework 2 - Translated Routes

Tags: zend-framework2

is there any solution to make translated routes in Zend Framework 2?

For example I need to do routes:

```
/en_US/orders/show/
/pl_PL/zamowienia/pokaz/
/de_DE/germany_orders/germany_show
```

How can I make it ?

Thanks at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This feature is not implemented yet, but will most likely follow with ZF 2.2

Comment: I think it's now `TranslatorAwareTreeRouteStack` - parametrized-locale-aware routing, see https://github.com/zendframework/zendframework/pull/5885